# CGI::Application::Plugin::JSON - json_body returns backwards

Tags: json, perl, cgi, cgi-application

I was wondering if anyone knew why this return is backwards with [CGI::Application::Plugin::JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~wonko/CGI-Application-Plugin-JSON-1.02/lib/CGI/Application/Plugin/JSON.pm#json_body)

```
sub {
    my ($self) = @_;

    my $q = $self->query;

    return $self->json_body({ result => '1', message => 'I should be AFTER result'} );

}
```

The Output is as follows:

`{"message":"I should be AFTER result","result":"1"}`

I would assume it would format the JSON left to right from the key/value pairs, and remembering it will be backwards is okay, but I have alot of returns to handle and the validation on the client-side is done with the 'result' value so if I am just missing something I would like to have it output just like it is input.

**EDIT**:

Also I just notices it is not returning a JSON Boolean type object as `"result":"1"` will deserialize as as sting object and not a JSON Boolean. Is there a way to have it output `"result":1`

Thanks for any help I can get with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would assume it would format the JSON left to right from the key/value pairs

You're confusing the list you assigned to the hash with the hash itself. Hashes don't have a left and a right; they have an array of linked lists.

You're getting the order in which the elements are found in the hash. You can't control that order as long as you use a hash.

If you really do need to have the fields in a specific order (which would be really weird), you could try using something that looks like a hash but remembers insertion order (like [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie%3a%3aIxHash)).

> remembering it will be backwards is okay

Not only are they not "backwards", the order isn't even predictable.

```
$ perl -MJSON -E'say encode_json {a=>1,b=>2,c=>3} for 1..3'
{"b":2,"c":3,"a":1}
{"c":3,"a":1,"b":2}
{"a":1,"c":3,"b":2}
```

> Is there a way to have it output `"result":1`

`result => 1`

Comment: I figured it was due to the randomness of hash ordering and a another module just to do that for my OCDs sack is not worth it, but it was a stumper as it always returned the same way (100 iterations or so) so I was not sure if the Module was doing something weird with it. `Tie::IxHash` was exactly what I was looking for though and `result => 1` works prefect. Thanks so much, its time to stop coding and get back to the "real" world of Los Santos now....

Comment: (It's harder to trigger variations in order before 5.18)